# How can i uncheck all the checkboxes depending on the drop down value

Tags: jquery

I have a combo box , On change of the drop down how can i uncheck all the checkboxes 
that are having a different value other than the selected status

http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/11/

I am unable to keep that condition under drop down change

```
$(document).on('change', 'select#filterstatus', function (event) {


    var value = $(this).val();
    $(".Table_fluid").show();
    $(".Table_fluid:not(:contains(" + value + "))").hide();



});
```

Scenario :

**I click on Mark All CheckBox (At the top) and chnage the status and click on the delete button 
its showing other ids also**

could anybody please let me know how to resolve this issue .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `.find("[type=checkbox]").prop("checked", false);` after `.hide()`.

See it working [here](http://jsfiddle.net/mayn3dt8/).

```
var value = $(this).val(),
    selectAll = $("#selectall").prop("checked"); // select all checked?

$(".Table_fluid")
    .show()
    .find("[type=checkbox]")
    .prop("checked", selectAll); //  tick checkbox on showing

$(".Table_fluid:not(:contains(" + value + "))")
    .hide()
    .find("[type=checkbox]")
    .prop("checked", false);  // uncheck checkbox on hiding
```

Comment: Thank you very much , When i click on mark all and change the status , the checkbox status is being lost

Comment: @PreethiJain what do you mean? the "mark all" checkbox?

Comment: I select Mark all checkbox , and click on delete button and now chnage the status to pending and now again chnage the status to declined .
In this case the checkbox selection on the Table Item (TR) is lost

Comment: @PreethiJain I got what you mean.

Comment: perfect its working exactly as needed , thank you very very much .

Answer (score 0):

In the label (inside the Table) that has the value of the status, add the following class `label-status`.

```
$.each($checked, function (i, e) {
    var status = $(e).parent().parent().find('.label-status').text();
    if ($(e).attr("id") != 'selectall' && status == $('#filterstatus').val()) {
        ids.push($(e).attr("id"))
    }
});
```

**EDIT**: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cdkLkcdk/13/)

Answer (score 0):

May be you can check whether the item is visible.

```
if ($(e).attr("id") != 'selectall' && $(e).is(":visible")) {
    ids.push($(e).attr("id"))
}
```